# DataTables jquery.dataTables.min.js:181 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I can't specify what/where is the problem, here is my code :

HTML :

```
                    <table id="companies" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="center">
                                Id
                            </th>
                            <th>RegNo</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th class="hidden-480">Industry</th>

                            <th class="hidden-phone">
                                Size
                            </th>
                            <th class="hidden-480">LineOfDefence</th>

                            <th>Address</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
```

Server side :

```
   var result = new
    {
        rows = (from company in db.Company.ToList()
                select new
                {
                    id = company.CompanyId,
                    RegNo = company.RegestrationNumber,
                    Name = company.Name,
                    Industry = company.IndustryType.Name,
                    Size = company.CompanySize.Name,
                    LineOfDefence = company.LineOfDefence.Name,
                    Address = company.Address
                }).ToArray()
    };
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and here is my Ajax Call :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#companies').DataTable( {
            "ajax": {
                url: "/Company/GetCompanyGrid",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm getting this error : "jquery.dataTables.min.js:181 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

note : I'm using jquery-1.12.3.js & DataTables 1.10.12.

Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: your call reach to controller to fetch records? and also show datatable bind properties like paging, sorting, columns etc

Answer (score 1):

finally I've figured out the problem :

first : datatables expects specific format, so I changed my server side code like this :

```
var result = new
            {
                **draw = 1,
                recordsTotal = db.Company.ToList().Count,
                recordsFiltered = db.Company.ToList().Count,**
                data = (from company in db.Company.ToList()
                        select new
                        {
                            Id = company.CompanyId,
                            RegNo = company.RegestrationNumber,
                            Name = company.Name,
                            Industry = company.IndustryType.Name,
                            Size = company.CompanySize.Name,
                            LineOfDefence = company.LineOfDefence.Name,
                            Address = company.Address,

                        }).ToArray()
            };
            return Json(result
            , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

second : I've added these lines to my script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#companies').DataTable( {
            "ajax": {
                url: "/Company/GetCompanyGrid",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json"
            },"columns": [
            { "data": "Id" },
            { "data": "RegNo" },
            { "data": "Name" },
            { "data": "Industry" },
            { "data": "Size" },
            { "data": "LineOfDefence" },
            { "data": "Address" },
            { "data": "Logo" },
            { "data": null },
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

and now it's working perfectly.

Comment: No need to add `draw`, `recordsTotal` and `recordsFiltered` properties, these are needed for server-side processing mode **only** which you don't use, `data` property is the only one needed for the mode you use, see [Ajax](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax). You can also accept your own answer to close it.

Answer (score 0):

Datatables expects the returned json to be in a specific format, as per the [documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) - see the 'Returned data' section.

Your json should look something like this:

```
return Json(new
{
      param.draw,
      recordsTotal = result.Count,
      recordsFiltered = result.Count,
      data = result
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The error is probably a result of datatables looking for a field that isn't present.  Note that the `draw` value is sent in the original `GetCompanyGrid()` request, you don't need to generate it yourself.

Comment: OP hasn't use any paging so may be not this issue, i have asked op to show datatable bind properties, so we have better idea

Comment: @SandipPatel - it doesn't matter, datatables still EXPECTS to recieve those parameters.

Comment: I made the changes, now it gives me another error :

Comment: datatables unknown parameter 0 for row 0

Comment: Do you know that the data is returning correctly?  Can you see the response in the console's 'Net' panel?

Comment: the issue was resolved as I've explained above, thanks a lot buddy @markpsmith

Comment: No need to add `draw`, `recordsTotal` and `recordsFiltered` properties, these are needed for server-side processing mode **only** which OP don't use, `data` property is the only one needed , see [Ajax](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax).